# Possible bug with Samsung roms?

Tags: android

I'm currently working in an app that shows a contact list to the user.

In that list, the name, the contact picture and the email of the contact must be shown, so I get the list like this:

```
final Cursor c = managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE + "="+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME , null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

int tamano= c.getCount();      

Log.e("USER", "The size of the contact list is : " + tamano);
```

And here's the thing...

I've tried it in 3 samsung mobiles (2 Galaxy SII and 1 Galaxy ACE), and 2 HTC (1 HTC Desire S and 1 HTC Wildfire).

The results are, at least, funny:

With all the galaxies:

The size of the contact list is : 9

With the HTC:

The size of the contact list is 482

All the phones are sync with the same gmail account, so have the same number of contacts...

How is this possible? Is there a bug or something in the Samsung roms?

Greetings!

***EDIT WITH SOLUTION:

IT WORKS! And now I know what the problem is:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME
```

The thing is that samsung doesn't organize the contacts the same way HTC does, and now it's fixed with this small change:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_OTHER
```

Now all the contacts appear in all the phones (except in Galaxy Ace, but might be because of the strange rom it has...) THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your query like so...

```
= managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI
, null
, ContactsContract.DATA.MIMETYPE+"=? AND "+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE+"=?"
, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.Content_Item_Type, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME}
, ContactsContract.DATA.DISPLAY_NAME );
```

I didn't test this but should be right or similar.

a naive method to display a Cursor to help with debugging

```
public static void displayCursor(Cursor c){
    int columnCount;
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        columnCount = c.getColumnCount();
        do{
            Log.i(" ", "********************");
            for(int i=0;i<columnCount;i++){
                try{ 
                    Log.i(c.getColumnName(i)+":", c.getString(i)+" ");
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly the same... keeps returning 9 contacts...

By the way, the code is:

    = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI , null,   ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"=? AND "+ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE+"=?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME+""}, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME );

Comment: so i would also check visibility of contacts (although this shouldn't matter im just curious). Also remove the type matching as maybe the aggregation in older devices did not associate types correctly and see if sizes match. If that is correct I would proceed to just display the results.. i wrote a very naive display function ill put in for debugging

Comment: IT WORKS! And now I know what the problem is:

     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME

The thing is that samsung doesn't organize the contacts the same way HTC does, and now it's fixed with this small change:

     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_OTHER


Now all the contacts appear in all the phones (except in Galaxy Ace, but might be because of the strange rom it has...)

THANKS!